# Installing and using docker on 32 bit machine

Tags: docker

I know that the official support is only for 64-bit but I can see from a few people have tried to custom build the docker binaries for 32-bit and succeeded (32-bit version of docker maybe a little unstable but it is fine for my use-case).

However, most of those blogs are old and do not work. Is there anyone who has done this recently?

I'm trying to build docker on 2 machines (i686) running with debian - wheezy and stretch (with kernel > 3.10; the minimum required). Has at-least 2GB of RAM and sufficient disk space.

Comment: Too broad, voted to close

Answer (score 1):

There's 32bit docker on 32bit ARM machines, i think i've seen it done on RPis and ODROIDs at least.

On 32bit x86... i doubt you'll find much. It's not that it's impossible (if there's 32bit ARM docker, there can be 32bit x86 docker), but nobody cares enough. You *can* run 32bit docker images (in fact i've done it recently) on a 64bit system, but docker itself...